# How to set Image and Button In qr Code scanner Screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, qr-code

I'm looking to make a barcode scanner app. As I'm new to Swift and Xcode I've managed to get help from other stack-overflow articles to create a page where I can scan a barcode. My issue is I don't want full screen, I want to add Label on top and Button at bottom and In Center QRCode screen. I have Uploaded Screen as well. [image: This is My Expected Screen]

But I'm Getting Full Screen. How can I achieve This Functionality.
Here's My Code

```
@IBAction func scanButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    scanQRCodeTapped()
}




func scanQRCodeTapped(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            
            print("No Device Found")
            return
        }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            self.failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (self.captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            self.captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            self.failed()
            return
        }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)

        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    
}
func failed() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    present(ac, animated: true)
    captureSession = nil
}

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }

        guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: stringValue)
        login(emailID: stringValue)

    }

    dismiss(animated: true)  
}


func found(code: String) {
    print(code)
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design the screen as per your design in the storyboard.

Like this:

[image]

The Gray color area is a `UIView` in which we will add the `previewLayer` for scanner.

ViewController code should look like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class QRCodeViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scannerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scanButton: UIButton!
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func scanButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        scanQRCodeTapped()
    }
    
    func scanQRCodeTapped() {
        self.scannerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
                print("No Device Found")
                return
            }
            let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
            do {
                videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            } catch {
                return
            }
            if (self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
                self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
            } else {
                
                self.failed()
                return
            }
            let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            if (self.captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
                self.captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
                metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
            } else {
                self.failed()
                return
            }
            self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.scannerView.layer.bounds
            self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            self.scannerView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
        
    }
    
    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
            login(emailID: stringValue)
            
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    
    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
    }

}
```

The output will look like this when you click on the scan button:

[image]

Comment: can we use front camera for scanning? is there any possibilities?